# True False parameters in Angular HTML, but what if there is a third option?

Tags: angularjs

We all know that using the true false (or in this case 0 and 1) works just fine, like this:

```
{{ vm.searchPaid ? "SHOW PAID" : "SHOW UN-PAID" }}
```

But what if I have a 3rd option? what if `vm.searchPaid` can be 0, 1 or 2

```
{{ vm.searchPaid ? "SHOW PAID" : "SHOW UN-PAID" : "SHOW ALL" }}
```

Is this in any way possible or would I have to write a function in js and call that instead?

Or is there another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible, you need to write a function with the switch case instead, or use **[`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)** in template

Comment: Ahhh!  ng-switch - didnt even know there was one.  ng-switch and ng-switch-then.  That would take a tiny bit more code, but its doable :)  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is possible, but IMHO not looking very nice. Use at your own judgement.

```
{{ (vm.searchPaid == 0) ? "SHOW PAID" : (vm.searchPaid == 1) ? "SHOW UN-PAID" : "SHOW ALL" }}
```

Assuming the value will always be 0,1 or 2, which might or might not always be the case.